# FreeBSD switching name and size different files after upload

Tags: freebsd, file-transfer, ftp

I`ve faced with strange problem.

When I uploaded files via FTP (using FileZilla as FTP-client) to server with FreeBSD7.3, i see strange things: some (4-5%) of all uploaded files changed their contents to another files.

Ie. i upload these files:

> big-file.php (100Kb)
>   small-file.php (15Kb)

I`ve get these:

> big-file.php (15Kb)
>   small-file.php (100Kb)

And contents of these files is changed!

After that, i upload one more time - and files uploaded normally, except 1-2%. One more time - and all of them are normal.
Sometimes i need get to the specified folder, take a look of filenames and filesizes and (if there is differnet between server and my repository) upload one more time.

What is that? Anybody had it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a [known issue in FileZilla](http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/1270), where file names are swapped around when you transfer multiple files. The author blames the FTP server, though considering that [such bugs also occur with sftp](http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/1072), which doesn't use the FTP protocol, I find this claim dubious.

Comment: Thnx, Gilles! Using another FTP-client (FAR manager) decided my problem.